# Adding extention_attributes to Oder not working

Tags: magento2, orders, api, magento2.2, extension-attributes

There's an extension in my project and I want to include one of its attributes in the Order object so that Zapier can see that field.

I don't have to save that field, it's saved somewhere else, so I just want to append it in the Order object inside `extension_attributes`.

Here's the approach:

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="save_custom" type="My\Project\Plugin\OrderSave"/>
        <plugin name="get_custom" type="My\Project\Plugin\OrderGet"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

extension_attribute.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="custom" type="My\Project\Api\Data\CustomAttributeInterface" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Api/CustomInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Project\Api\Data;

interface CustomInterface
{
    const NAME = 'custom';

    /**
     * Return value.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getValue();

    /**
     * Set value.
     *
     * @param string|null $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setValue($value);
}
```

OrderGet.php

```
<?php

// ... some code

class OrderGet
{

    // constructor and other code...

    public function afterGet(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $resultOrder
    ) {
        $resultOrder = $this->getCustomAttribute($resultOrder);

        return $resultOrder;
    }


    private function getCustomAttribute(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        try {
            $somwhere = $this->someFactory->create();
            $somwhere->load($order->getIncrementId(), 'order_id');

            if (!$somwhere->getId()) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException('No custom entity found for id' . $order->getIncrementId());
            }

            // This will get the custom value from the database
            $customAttributeValue = $this->someHelper->getCustomConfig($somwhere->getData('some_id'));

        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $order;
        }

        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $orderExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
        $customAttribute = $this->customAttributeFactory->create();
        $customAttribute->setValue($customAttributeValue);
        $orderExtension->setCustomAttribute($customAttribute);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($orderExtension);

        return $order;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? And how can I include the same custom field in the api call to /orders not only /order/:id.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<?php

// ... some code

class OrderGet
{

    // constructor and other code...

    public function afterGet(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $resultOrder
    ) {
        $resultOrder = $this->getCustomAttribute($resultOrder);

        return $resultOrder;
    }


    private function getCustomAttribute(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        try {
            $somwhere = $this->someFactory->create();
            $somwhere->load($order->getIncrementId(), 'order_id');

            if (!$somwhere->getId()) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException('No custom entity found for id' . $order->getIncrementId());
            }

            // This will get the custom value from the database
            $customAttributeValue = $this->someHelper->getCustomConfig($somwhere->getData('some_id'));

        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $order;
        }

        $extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes();     
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {     
            $extensionAttributes = $this->getOrderExtensionDependency();     
        }

        $orderExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
        $orderExtension->setCustomAttribute($customAttribute);
        $customAttribute = $this->customAttributeFactory->create();
        $customAttribute->setValue($customAttributeValue);

        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $order;
    }

    private function getOrderExtensionDependency() 
    {    
        $orderExtensionFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            '\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface'
        );   
        return $orderExtension;  
    }
}
```